# async_schedule vs workqueue in linux

Tags: asynchronous, linux-kernel

I'm looking for some guidelines on which cases to use what mechanism.
More specific I'm trying to create collisions in a unit-test. I want multiple contexts to inject a bunch of requests to test it. I have seen an example with workqueues, and, created my own test with async_schedule. So I want to know what method fits best this scenario and why?

Also some guidelines for the future will be appreciated.

I know workqueues can handle multiple tasks queued to them. And that async_schedule will most likely open a separate kthread for each task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`async_schedule` internally uses workqueues.](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/async.c?v=3.8#L215).

You could achieve the same using **`create_singlethread_workqueue()`** i.e multiple workqueues each with its own thread to execute "work".

More details in this **[chapter on workqueues from LDD3](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-6)**.